# How to search if certain field of table already contain specific value using VBA in ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would like to do something like,

```
if field table "name" of table "listuser" already contain "john",
   update the "id" field to 1234.
else - create a new record with name "john" 
   and update the id field to 1234.
```

how to write the "field table "name" of table "listuser" already contain "john"" part in vba?

Comment: Is `id` in the `listuser` table? If there is a `john` record, which record's `id` field gets updated to 1234? All of them? Just the `john`s?

Comment: Why VBA and not SQL?

Comment: @Brad yes, id is a field from listuser table, just record the id of john.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combo of VBA and SQL seems like it can handle this

If we define two queries we can use them in VBA

`UpdateListUser`:

```
PARAMETERS newId Long, userName Text ( 255 );
UPDATE listuser SET listuser.id = iif(newId is null, listuser.id, newId)
WHERE (((listuser.[name])=userName));
```

and `InsertNewUser`:

```
PARAMETERS newId Long, userName Text ( 255 );
INSERT INTO Listuser ( id, name )
VALUES (newId, username);
```

You would make and save these using the Create > Query Design > SQL View window in the regular Access interface.

Then to use them in VBA you can have a function like this

```
Dim id As Integer, username As String
id = 1234
username = "John"

Dim cmd As New DAO.QueryDef
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb

Dim updListUser As DAO.QueryDef
Set updListUser = db.QueryDefs("UpdateListUser")
updListUser.Parameters("newId") = id
updListUser.Parameters("UserName") = username
updListUser.Execute

Debug.Print updListUser.RecordsAffected

If updListUser.RecordsAffected = 0 Then
    Dim insertNewUser As DAO.QueryDef
    Set insertNewUser = db.QueryDefs("InsertNewUser")
    insertNewUser.Parameters("newId") = id
    insertNewUser.Parameters("UserName") = username
    insertNewUser.Execute
End If
```

Comment: nice. one question though, if i want to make the UpdateListUser to skip inputing if the ID is not blank, can I write like this?

PARAMETERS newId Long, userName Text ( 255 );
UPDATE listuser 
IIf ([id] =null,SET listuser.id = newId , null)  
WHERE (((listuser.[name])=userName));

Comment: @Leon Are you asking that if you pass in a null `id` can the update query set listuser.id to null? Or, the way I'm reading `IIf ([id] =null,SET listuser.id = newId , null) `, I see If `id` is null then set listuser.id = null (because id = null) otherwise do nothing. ?

Comment: sorry, what i meant is if the id is not null, it skip inputting new value on id field. IIf ([id] =null, [leave id value alone] , SET listuser.id = newId). Is it possible to add command inside conditional like this?

Comment: @Leon see my edit, this will not allow the update statement to let id ever be null. Now if you really need this strictly enforced you should design your table such that it can never happen anyway. Mark `id` as either the primary key (likely given the column name) or make it a required column.

Comment: Thanks, is there any other way running query with passing parameter like that without using DAO?

Comment: @Leon You can use ADO, the syntax is different, but that's the other way. DAO is the default. Is there a reason you don't want DAO?

Comment: the computer I use has some kind of ridiculous admin restriction stuff that won't let me change the reference, even ADO and DAO not checked on reference. If I use DoCmd.RunSQL, is there any way to apply the conditional? well at least to search if the field name on table contain "john". Thank you for your help and patience.